# Replace string in log4j2 filename in RollingFileAppender

Tags: regex, log4j2

I am trying to replace a string in a environment variable that I use in the filename as shown below. But the output file is generated literally with '%replace'. Is it possible to do such a replacement? If not, any other options? Essentially, I want to replace 'abc' with blank in the environment variable ${current.env}

```
    <RollingFile name="FileA"
        fileName="${sys:file.path}/%replace{${sys:current.env}}{'abc'}{}-xyz.log"
        filePattern="${sys:file.path}/%replace{${sys:current.env}}{'abc'}{}-xyz-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
```

Comment: Are you really asking about an [environment variable](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup) or a [system property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#SystemPropertiesLookup) ? The configuration you shared is using the latter.

Comment: As far as modifying the results of a [lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html), I don't know of any such feature in log4j2. You could [create a custom lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/extending.html#Lookups) to do it.

Comment: Thanks @D.B. The issue is how to replace a string in the file name config. Whether the value is a system or environment property does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code showing how to create a custom lookup that is able to replace strings within the lookup result.

First the class that generates the logging:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        log.info("Here's some info!");
        log.error("Some error happened!");
    }
}
```

Next the class that defines the custom lookup:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

@Plugin(name = "sysWithReplace", category = "Lookup")
public class SystemLookupWithReplace implements StrLookup{
    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value for the key.
     */
    public String lookup(String key) {
        if(key == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(!key.contains(";")){
            return System.getProperty(key);
        }
        String[] params = key.split(";");

        String value = System.getProperty(params[0]);
        if(params.length >= 2 && value != null){
            if(params.length < 3){
                return value.replace(params[1], "");
            }
            return value.replace(params[1], params[2]);
        }
        return value;
    }


    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key using the data in the LogEvent.
     * @param event The current LogEvent.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value associated with the key.
     */
    public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
        return lookup(key);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample log4j2.xml config file that uses the custom lookup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c ${sysWithReplace:os.name;dows 10;doze} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and finally the logging output (I'm running this on Windows 10 so it replaces the "dows 10" with "doze":

```
14:30:26.580 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass Windoze - Here's some info!
14:30:26.581 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass Windoze - Some error happened!
```